# parseplatform.org documentation disappeared

Tags: parse-platform

The guides and sdk docs on parseplatform.org were visible this morning, but now return 404s. Does anyone know if this was intentional?

Examples:

http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/  (Still viewable in Google search cache, but unformatted.)

http://parseplatform.org/docs/cloudcode/guide/  (I was able to save a complete version of this page on my laptop since I still had it up this morning.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the status of a third-party web site is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: I asked the question here because after searching for a while I couldn't find the documentation hosted anywhere else, and documentation is necessary for programming.

Comment: Because you couldn't find it somewhere else does not make an off-topic question become magically on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/parse-community/docs

Check out this repo. At the very bottom of the readme, it says:

> As of April 5, 2017, Parse, LLC has transferred this code to the parse-community organization, and will no longer be contributing to or distributing this code.

Looks like you should still be able to download the .md files of the docs though.